# Equivalence Proof (p ∧ q) ∨ ¬(p → q) ∨ ¬(q ∧ r).

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I am trying to prove (p ∧ q) ∨ ¬(p → q) ∨ ¬(q ∧ r)  ≡ ¬r ∨ (q → p).

So far I have done the following:

(p ∧ q) ∨ ¬(¬p ∨ q) ∨ ¬(q ∧ r) Implication Definition

(p ∧ q) ∨ (p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (¬q ∨ ¬r) De Morgan’s and Double Negation

I have no idea which law to use next, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(p\wedge q)\vee(p\wedge \neg q) \Rightarrow p\wedge(q\vee\neg q) \Rightarrow p$

Comment: Friend if I could give you a million rep, I would. I feel so stupid and thank you!

Comment: The use of the symbol $\;\Rightarrow\;$ seems to mean "simplifies to" here, correct?

Comment: @MarnixKlooster Yes, it means "simplifies to".